# Dynamo DB query fails through axios with Value null at 'tableName' failed to satisfy constraint

Tags: node.js, vue.js, postman, aws-api-gateway, amazon-dynamodb

I am making a query to `DynamoDB` via `API Gateway` and from `Postman` the request succeeds with `200 OK`, however through `Axios` (in a `VueJS` client) the code (as exported from `Postman`) fails with this error:

```
{"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"1 validation error detected: Value null at 'tableName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null"}
```

Here is the failing `Axios` code, which `Postman` generated (only slightly modified to hide the URL):

```
  let url = 'local/api/prospect'

  var data = JSON.stringify({
    "TableName":"my-table",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames":{"#lang":"LANGUAGE"},
    "ExpressionAttributeValues":{
      ":m":{"S":"Acet"},
      ":c":{"S":"CH"},
      ":l":{"S":"DE"}},
    "FilterExpression":"begins_with(MAT_DESC, :m) and COUNTRY = :c and #lang = :l"
  });

  var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: url,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    data: data
  }

  this.$axios(config)
```

Is there something `Postman` is doing internally which could cause this request to be successful but which the generated `NodeJS` request does not include?

**UPDATE**

I do not know why this works, but this code appears to have solved the problem...

```
  let url = 'local/api/prospect'

  var data = JSON.stringify({
    TableName: 'my-table',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {'#lang':'LANGUAGE'},
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{
      ':m':{S:'Acet'},
      ':c':{S:'CH'},
      ':l':{S:'DE'}},
    FilterExpression: 'begins_with(MAT_DESC, :m) and COUNTRY = :c and #lang = :l'
  })

  var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: url,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    data: data
  }
```

If anyone can tell me, categorically, why this is, please answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This one came down to the formatting of the request. Here is the correct way to format the data:

```
  var data = JSON.stringify({
    TableName: 'prospect-materials',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {'#lang':'LANGUAGE'},
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{
      ':m':{S:'Acet'},
      ':c':{S:'CH'},
      ':l':{S:'DE'}},
    FilterExpression: 'begins_with(MAT_DESC, :m) and COUNTRY = :c and #lang = :l'
  })
```